# yii2 сессия не работает

Tags: yii2

Не инициализируется сессия для неавторизированого пользователя  `$session = Yii::$app->session`. `$session->open()` тоже ничего не дает. Для авторизованых все работает отлично. В чем может быть проблема и как ее исправить? Спасибо

Comment: Раз пользователи авторизуются, значит сессия работает. Что значит "ничего не дает"? В чем это проявляется и что конкретно не работает?

Comment: елементарно - нету id сесии

Comment: Как проверяете это?

Comment: print_r($session = Yii::$app->session)

Comment: А если просто session_id() посмотреть? Да и проблема-то в чем? Вы же не id сессии на сайте показывать собираетесь. Переменные в сессию сохраняются?